# I want to use image in mdx file using gatsbyjs but it shows 2 images instead of one

Tags: gatsby

I am using an image in a mdx file but it shows 2 images instead of one of the same image.
The first one is blur whereas the second image turns out to be original image.I want to show only the original image.It seems like the blur image should be removed before the real image turns out but it shows even after the page has been loaded.

The mdx file is formatted as below

```
---
title: Examples
slug: "/examples"

---

Example screenshot


![](./assets/screenshot.png)
```

The gatsby-config.js file is formatted below

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
        `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
        `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
            options: {
                name: `docs`,
                path: `${__dirname}/src/docs/`,
            },
        },
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
            options: {
                gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
                    {
                        resolve: "gatsby-remark-images",
                    },
                ],
            }
        },
```

The image when showed in webpage turns out to be as below:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. I'll try to see if I can figure it out this weekend. Did you ever get anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Add a second "plugins" option in the mdx plugin options object with "gatsby-remark-images" repeated. This fixed it for me

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-mdx',
  options: {
    gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [ `gatsby-remark-images` ],
    plugins: [ `gatsby-remark-images` ],
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this, it basically same with the others one, but I just changed the syntax so that at least no warning errors show.

```
{
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-mdx',
      options: {
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [ `gatsby-remark-images` ],
        plugins: [ 
          {
            resolve : `gatsby-remark-images` 
          },
        ],
      }
    },
```